Can't upload files in Puppeteer, Chromium gives "Aw Snap!" error
I have been working with Puppeteer recently and I have been trying to work with file uploading. I've watched multiple tutorials and read the docs for Puppeteer, but everything I try always results in me getting this screen in Chromium (see attached image).
Here are two pieces of code that I have tried (cut out some of the stuff because sensitive data !):
const fileButton = await page.$("blah blah blah > input[type=file]");
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
                    page.waitForFileChooser(),
                    fileButton.evaluate(uploadButton => uploadButton.click())
                ])
await fileChooser.accept(["/validfilepath.pdf"]);

I've also tried doing this as well:
const fileButton = await page.$("blah blah blah > input[type=file]");
await fileButton.uploadFile("/validfilepath.pdf");

Both give me the exact same Aw Snap! screen on Chromium, does anyone know why this is the case and what I can do to resolve it? Thanks!


This is missing a [mcve]. What is the Puppeteer version and URL you're automating, and complete automation code? If there is sensitive data, can you create or find a non-sensitive page that reproduces the problem? Thanks.

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: false
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://ps.uci.edu/~franklin/doc/file_upload.html");
    const fileInput = await page.$("body > form > input[type=file]:nth-child(1)");
    const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForFileChooser(),
        fileInput.evaluate(uploadButton => uploadButton.click())
    ]);
    await fileChooser.accept([`any file goes here`]);
})();


Sorry for poor formatting but to reproduce all you need is some kind of file (ideally some pdf since that is the file that I am aiming to upload) and just put the path to that file in the section that says "any file goes here." The file upload still doesn't work here and it gives the exact same error. Puppeteer version is 22.12.1, and another quick note I tried reproduction with the .uploadFile() function as well and it still gives the same error.

Thanks, that looks reproducible. You can [edit] the post to show more code and clarify.
